# Insert line break into comment added to WorkItem in DevOps so that it appears correctly in the UI?

Tags: c#, azure-devops

I am using C# to update a Azure DevOps work item by adding a comment.  I cannot figure out how to insert a line break in the comment.

I am using code similar to this:

```
private async Task<WorkItem> updateWorkItemDetails(VssConnection connection, int workItemId, string buildnumber, string comment)
{
    JsonPatchDocument patchDocument = CreateUpdatePatchDocument(buildnumber, comment);

    // Get an instance of the work item tracking client
    WorkItemTrackingHttpClient witClient = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();

    return await witClient.UpdateWorkItemAsync(patchDocument, workitemId);
}

private JsonPatchDocument CreateUpdatePatchDocument(string buildNumber, string comment)
{
    var patchDocument = DevOpsHelper.CreateJsonPatchDocument(
        new JsonPatchOperation
        {
            Operation = Operation.Add,
            Path = "/fields/System.History",
            Value = comment
        }
    );

    return patchDocument;
}
```

I have tried passing "\r\n", "`<br />`" and "`n", but I cannot figure out anything that works.

What can I pass in to the comment argument to cause a line break to be appear in the UI on DevOps?

Actual result:
[image: Actual result]

Desired result:
[image: Desired result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments are stored as HTML with each line represented as a `<div>`. `<br/>` values are also supported.

```
"text": "<div>Here's a comment</div><div>with a line break</div><div><br></div><div>With two line breaks</div>"
```

Try using the `AddCommentAsync` method rather than patching the work-item history directly.

```cs
var projectName = "myProject";
var workItemId  = 12345;
var witClient = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();

var comment = new CommentCreate {
  text = "<div>My comment</div><br/><br/><br/><div>Has line breaks, yo!"
};

await witClient.AddCommentAsync(comment, projectName, workItemId);
```

[image: comments, yo!]